# Add Data with image in angular and webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, base64

I currently have some unresolved problems, specifically uploading images on the angular side (I'm using asp web api and angular)

On the web api side, I have the following controller:

```
 [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([FromForm] EmployeeViewModel employee)
  {
      var employ = new Employee
      {
          Name = employee.Name,
          Email = employee.Email,
          Phone = employee.Phone,
          Salary = employee.Salary,
      };
employ.ProfileImage = await ConvertImageBase.ImageToBase64(employee.FileImage);
           
      await _context.Employees.AddAsync(employ);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return Ok(employee);
  }
```

and class to convert from image to base64

```
namespace TestApi
{
         public static class ConvertImageBase
         {
             public static async Task<string> ImageToBase64(IFormFile image)
             {
                 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     await image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                     var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                     return Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                 }
             }
             public static async Task<IFormFile> Base64ToImage(string base64String, string namefile)
             {
                 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

                 var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                 var formFile = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, null, $"{namefile}.png");
                 return formFile;
             }
     }
}
```

On the view side I have the following html page:

```
<div class="container">
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmployee()">
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="name"
name="name"
[(ngModel)]="addEmployeerequest.name"
/>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="email"
name="email"
[(ngModel)]="addEmployeerequest.email"
/>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="phone"
name="phone"
[(ngModel)]="addEmployeerequest.phone"
/>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<label for="salary" class="form-label">Salary</label>
<input
type="number"
class="form-control"
id="salary"
min="0"
name="salary"
[(ngModel)]="addEmployeerequest.salary"
/>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and ts page writes logic

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/models/employee.model';
import { EmployeesService } from 'src/app/services/employees.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-employee',
templateUrl: './add-employee.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-employee.component.scss'],
})
export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
addEmployeerequest: Employee = {
id: 0,
name: '',
phone: '',
salary: 0,
email: '',
profileImage: '',
};

constructor(
private employeeService: EmployeesService,
private router: Router
) {}
ngOnInit(): void {}
addEmployee() {
this.employeeService.addEmployee(this.addEmployeerequest).subscribe({
next: (employee) => {
this.router.navigate(['employee']);
},
});
}
}
```

I tested on Swagger, the API works fine, I can upload images in base64 format and print the image view on Angular successfully, but when adding employees on the angular view, I always get an error. Now I can add fields like name, salary,... but when it comes to images, I always get error 415. I consulted gpt and some sources but they didn't work. I don't know if anyone can help me in this case. . Thank you all very much